# Run scheduled tasks in Java

Tags: java, sql

I want to run many tasks in my thread in respecting an order, this is my main Thread of the application:

```
@Component
public class LogExtractorApp extends CommonApp implements Runnable {

    UDPReceiver receiver = new UDPReceiver();

    public static Map<String, Entity> select;
    public static List<String> pdomain;

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    @Resource
    MessagesCounts counters;

    @Resource
    DbUpdating update;

    @Resource
    DeleteData delete;

    @Resource
    ExcludeDomain domain;   

    @Override
    public void run() {
       select = counters.main();
       pdomain = domain.main();
       ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
       service.execute(receiver);
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(update, 5, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
       service.execute(delete);
    }
}
```

and what i want when i start the application is the follow:

1. call the main method of counters.
2. call the main method of domain.
3. launch the Thread "receiver", this thread receive permanently data from a distant server.
4. launch a scheduled Thread to update the database every 5 minutes.
5. Recall the main method of counters. ( i mention here that map
   "select", is used in a method called by the thread "receiver").
6. Launch the thread "delete" to delete to delete all data from the
   database older then 1 day.

*I want that the three thread turn permanently of course *

My question: Step 1,2,3,4 work normally, but i don't know how to tell my application to recall the main method of "counters" every time after the "update" Thread to update the value of my map ("select"). And for the "delete" Thread i used to add it in the way showed in the code above, but it doesn't work like this. I appreciate any suggestion for my 2 questions, and if i have to add any other code the question, please to tell me by a commentary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For step 5 I thing , the timerTask class can help , 
Ref:http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html
Please refer java doc for more info.

If you stretch timerTask it can seve step 6 also , but there is another neat tool for scheduling java tasks , Quartz , http://quartz-scheduler.org/
You can find more about the configuration in their web site.

Comment: this not what i want, i don't want to use timer, all that i need is to run a method, at the end of a Thread @Manu